# Failed to open the app just upload in Play Store java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Tags: android, facebook

Good I have an app of Stikers wsp, https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers and previously I had it without problems and yesterday try to update it, I added some advertising and a few more buttons. When testing from Android Studio works perfectly but when uploading the app and open it already downloaded from the play store closes and the play console tells me the following:

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:318)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:354)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:223)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:243)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.b (Unknown Source)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.nativecode.d.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.facebook.animated.webp.WebPImage.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.Stikers.Strikers.i.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.Stikers.Strikers.i.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.Stikers.Strikers.i.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.Stikers.Strikers.h.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.Stikers.Strikers.EntryActivity$a.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.Stikers.Strikers.EntryActivity$a.doInBackground (Unknown Source)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:304)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
```

Delete these modifications that I had made to rule out possible errors and the problem does not follow. Whenever I upload it to the play store it generates this error I happened to leave the gradle.

```
      apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    //the compression of webp file during build causes problem with FileDescriptor in ContentProvider.
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "webp"
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Stikers.Stikers"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 12
        versionName "3.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        def contentProviderAuthority = applicationId + ".stickercontentprovider"
        // Creates a placeholder property to use in the manifest.
        manifestPlaceholders =
                [contentProviderAuthority: contentProviderAuthority]
        // Adds a new field for the authority to the BuildConfig class.
        buildConfigField("String",
                "CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY",
                "\"${contentProviderAuthority}\"")
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so"
            exclude '/lib/mips64/**'
            exclude '/lib/arm64-v8a/**'
            exclude '/lib/x86_64/**'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

task checkDebug {
    doLast {
        println("checkDebug")
        if (android.defaultConfig.applicationId.startsWith("com.whatsapp")) {
            throw new GradleException("applicationId in defaultConfig cannot start with com.whatsapp, please change your applicationId in app/build.gradle");
        }
        checkApplicationIdInDebug()
    }
}

private void checkApplicationIdInDebug() {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    def ignoreApplicationIdCheck = properties.getProperty('ignoreApplicationIdCheck')
    if (ignoreApplicationIdCheck == null) {
        if (android.defaultConfig.applicationId.equals("com.example.samplestickerapp")) {
            throw new GradleException("Your applicationId is currently com.example.samplestickerapp, please change your applicationId to a different string in app/build.gradle in line 16");
        }
    } else {
        println("application id check ignored")
    }
}


task checkRelease {
    doLast {
        println("checkRelease")
        if (android.defaultConfig.applicationId.startsWith("com.example")) {
            throw new GradleException("applicationId in defaultConfig cannot start with com.example, please change your applicationId in app/build.gradle");
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    println(task.name)
    if (task.name.contains("assembleDebug")) {
        task.dependsOn checkDebug
    }
    if (task.name.contains("assembleRelease")) {
        task.dependsOn checkRelease
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
}



download the
```

github app code again https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers, change the name of the package, sign the app and upload it as a test. Bone without changing anything at all and the problem continued.